# Loop through NSDictionary in key order displayed with NSLog

Tags: objective-c, json, nsdictionary

I'm getting an `NSDictionary` trough `JSON`. When doing a `NSLog` the key order is the following: *40617*, *40737*, *40946*, *41066*, *41306*. That's the order I want because the values are sorted beforehand. But when looping trough the `NSDictionary` I get the following order: *40617*, *41066*, *40737*, *40946*, *41306*. Is it possible to get it in the order I see when I use `NSLog`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `NSDictionary` is not ordered by definition, so when you add the values, they don't have to be the same order all the time. If you want an ordered collection you should use a `NSArray`

Answer (score 4):

Dictionaries (maps) are unsorted. There is no guaranteed order when you iterate them. You're only guaranteed to get all entries.

So you need to get the keys, sort them in a way you want, and then get the values for your sorted keys.

For example:

```
NSArray *keys = [myDictionary allKeys];
NSArray *sortedKeys = [keys sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

for (id key in sortedKeys) {
    id value = [myDictionary objectForKey:key];

    NSLog(@"%@ = %@", key, value);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't have that option by default. You have to customize.

http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/12/ordereddictionary-subclassing-cocoa.html

Comment: Ugh, that's an ugly and bloated solution for such a tiny problem. I'm pretty sure Matt only implemented this to show how to subclass a dictionary if you really need to. His very first header is: **Best practice: don't subclass**

Comment: Besides, this is so old, it neither implements `NSFastEnumeration` nor block based enumeration.